# xsl string-join() force to include empty values

Tags: xslt

Hi everyone i have simple xslt code for transformation xml to csv and than save csv to db, that's why if i have to include empty values in csv.
For example i want this output: `value1,value2,vaule3,,vaule5` but a have `value1,value2,vaule3,vaule5`

Example of xslt code.

```
 <xsl:value-of
            select="string-join((xpath1,xpath2,xpath3,xpath4),',')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924888/xsl-string-join-multiple-variables-only-use-non-empty) has the exact opposite problem. I would suggest saving the values of xpath1...xpath4 into variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to force the conversion of non-existing elements to an empty string so `(string(xpath1), string(xpath2), string(xpath3), string(xpath4))` should do.